# How to have a Button centered vertically besides an image

Tags: html, css

How would I go about centering this button besides the image?
`top:50%` won't work as the parent does not have a fixed size

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            <div class="btn-group btn-block" role="group">
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-warning" style="top:50%;">Sign in
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a `fiddle` example:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/#&togetherjs=d6NLIis7u4

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this?

Comment: What is fiddle...?

Comment: It's a website where you can showcase your code. See https://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: try using `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: @BikasVaibhav cool! Thanks for introducing it to me!!! Edited the question to add a fiddle example.

Comment: Have you import bootstrap library?

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty paragraph? Would that have actual text in it in the real page?

Answer (score 0):

I used `display: table`, `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` tricks, among others, on this one:

https://jsfiddle.net/qh7nrcyh/1/

Please check if it works on you.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to vertically center something with css is using line-height. But this only works if you have a fixed height and a single line of text.